# Guidelines to work on WinForms Form in Visual Studio 2010 simultaneously (at least partially)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I was one programmer for my entire career and never had to work with someone else. Recently I've hired a new programmer that is very young (inexperienced) to help me out with my projects. The problem we're hitting is that our Main GUI is holding a lot of `UI elements` like `TabControl` with `0-15 tabs` (and that's just 4months into development), some navigation bars etc. We're using Visual Studio 2010 Pro and Ultimate with `DevExpress` controls.

We've been trying a lot to keep as much as possible things separated from each other (so we've got lots of small files with different stuff - so that we can both work together on different parts).

We've been using `partial classes` for most things and the small GUI's aren't the problem.

```
public partial class Act {

}
```

The only problem we're hitting is the main interface which is `CENTER of the Universe`. 
Is there a way that `Designer` and other pieces of code can be cut into pieces? Like if I would like `TabControl` to be separated into another file and then each `Tab` from this `TabControl` would be separated further ? Are there guidelines to work on this kind of things?

I guess for most people it's probably basic programmer's stuff but since I've been working myself all the time and my background is mostly Administration I've never really needed to grasp working in a Team on GUI based projects.

We're using `Tortoise SVN` but we do have license for Visual Studio Team Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to break apart the controls just so you two can work on them independently.  You can resolve conflicts when you commit your changes in [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html).

You may want to separate them because of design/maintenance considerations.  For example a TabControl with 15 tabs seems overkill - you are probably cramming too much different functionality into one form.

Answer (score 1):

Like previous answer suggested, use proper version control and resolve conflicts manually.

Also, you can create [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) and then incorporate those to the main UI. Especially if those controls are needed in some other forms.

If you want to educate yourself about UI design and avoid cramming too much stuff into one form, you might want to have a look of this link. It might be that your problem's root cause might be in this area.

- [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511279.aspx)

Comment: You gave me idea with that `UserControls`. This might actually work :-)